# Deleting SQLite database : How to?

Tags: database, sqlite

There is this particular database named temp which I want to delete which was created using SQLite on  ubuntu machine. How do I delete this databse?

Comment: SQLite databases are just files. You can delete the database by deleting the file. Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/about.html

Comment: Where will the files be present in ubuntu?

Comment: Delete the file. Where is the file? where the programme using it place it.

Answer (score 2):

The case is quite simple.

Either delete the file like this :

```
rm -fr filename
```

Or in terminal type something like :

```
$ sqlite3 tempfile (where tempfile is the name of the file)

sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

You will see a list of tables like this as an example:

```
table|friends|friends|2|CREATE TABLE friends (id int)
```

then just type

```
sqlite> drop table friends (or the name you want to drop)
```

Then press ctrl-d to exit.

It is that simple

Answer (score 0):

SQLite saves data to a file. Leverage the methods tailored to the specific OS so you can delete the file. I.E. with Android use the System.IO.File.Delete() method.

Here is some code showing what I used to create and delete my SQLite database on an android device in C#:

```
public class SQLite_DB 
{
    private string databasePath;

    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
    {
        databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "sqlite_db.db3");
        SQLiteAsyncConnection database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
        return database;
    }

    public bool DeleteDatabase()
    {
        File.Delete(databasePath);

        if (File.Exists(databasePath))
        return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

For Ubuntu, a simple rm -rf [database path/filename] should suffice.

Comment: Note that there can remain `databasePath + "-journal"`, `databasePath + "-wal"` and/or `databasePath + "-shm"` files left over if the application crashed or the journal/WAL is permanent.